# BOOLEAN value inserted if checkbox is checked MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get values from a form into my database as boolean type.

Basically, each question has many checkboxes, and if a user checks the box, i want it to put in 1 for true and whichever ones are not checked to insert 0.

I have attempted to get them in, however no luck.

Please see additional code/snippets below.

Can someone please help?

```
  <h1>Question 1</h1><br>
   </br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">Item1
 <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">Item2
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="button-form">
```

PHP CODE:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 try{

    $Query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Results ( 1, 2 ) VALUES (:1, :2)');
        $Query->execute();
```

Comment: If you want a value of `1`, why are you setting the values the same as the names? And note that unchecked checkboxes are not sent to the server.

Comment: B1 is the name defined in the database, i want it to give value of 1 IF CHECKED?

Comment: You might want to look into using array_key_exists().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a checkbox isn't checked, it's not sent. That means it is **not set to zero** if unchecked.

What does that mean? It means you need to check if it's sent or not. If yes, it's 1, if not - it's 0.

The code you're after is the following:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
            ':UserID' =>$_POST['UserID'],
            ':B1' => isset($_POST['B1']) ? 1 : 0,
            ':B2' => isset($_POST['B2']) ? 1 : 0, 
            ':B2' => isset($_POST['B3']) ? 1 : 0,
            ':B2' => isset($_POST['B4']) ? 1 : 0,
            ':B2' => isset($_POST['B5']) ? 1 : 0,
            ':B2' => isset($_POST['B6']) ? 1 : 0
            ));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have put that in, but it is carrying 0 to all answers to the database still?

Comment: Your query inserts only 3 values. `INSERT INTO Results ($UserID, B1, B2 ) `. I can't see what the http headers are so it's a bit impossible to aid further without additional input from you..

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox isn't checked (see "checked"-Attribute of input type checkbox), nothing is sent to the server.
`$_POST['B1']` gets the value of the element with NAME 'B1' if it is sent to the server.

So

```
$b1 = (isset($_POST['B1'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

should do the trick. $b1 will be 0 if the checkbox is unchecked and 1 if it is checked.

**Option 1**
The SQL looks like you are trying to put something like 01100 into the database field 'B2'.
Usually you would store the result of every checkbox in a single database column. But if you really want to concat them, your code should look like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO Results ($UserID, B1, B2 ) VALUES (:UserID, :B1, :B2, :B3, :B4, :B5, :B6);');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':UserID' =>$_POST['UserID'],
        ':B1' =>$_POST['B1'],
        ':B2' =>(isset($_POST['B2'])) ? 1 : 0 + (isset($_POST['B3'])) ? 1 : 0 + (isset($_POST['B4'])) ? 1 : 0 + (isset($_POST['B5'])) ? 1 : 0 + (isset($_POST['B6'])) ? 1 : 0
        ));
```

**Option 2**
If you have one database field for every B1...B6-value then you've forgotten to take these columns into your SQL-INSERT-Statement:

```
INSERT INTO Results ($UserID, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6) [...]
```

And your stmt execute is wrong and should be:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
        ':UserID' =>$_POST['UserID'],
        ':B1' => isset($_POST['B1']) ? 1 : 0,
        ':B2' => isset($_POST['B2']) ? 1 : 0, 
        ':B3' => isset($_POST['B3']) ? 1 : 0,
        ':B4' => isset($_POST['B4']) ? 1 : 0,
        ':B5' => isset($_POST['B5']) ? 1 : 0,
        ':B6' => isset($_POST['B6']) ? 1 : 0
        ));
```

Comment: Do it like N.B. mentioned above: ':B1' => isset($_POST['B1']) ? 1 : 0, ... But take care - your SQL isn't complete. You're inserting ($UserID, B1, B2 ) only. You should take the other columns in addition.

Comment: Is there an easier way with: ':B1' =>$_POST['B1'], as I have perhaps 30 checkboxes, or is that the way it has to be done?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could provide more information of what are you doing - Option 1 (storing 0/1 of ALL questions in ONE database field) or Option 2 (storing EVERY single 0/1 in a SINGLE database field).

Comment: Option 2 - Storing EVERY single 0/1 in a single database field.